# Cant make it print if a word isnt found in my word search project

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code for the main body. Which goes through a string of character formats them and then searches words in a inputed list.
the string of characters is

```
'WAQHGTTWEECBMIVQQELSAZXWKWIIILLDWLFXPIPVPONDTMVAMNOEDSOYQGOBLGQCKGMMCTYCSLOACUZMXVDMGSXCYZUUIUNIXFNU'
```

and the string of words is `'UNIX CALPOLY GCC SLO COMPILE VIM TEST'`
my code correctly finds the words in all directions how ever the issue is when it doesn't find the word.

```
import funcs


def main():
    rawPuzzle = funcs.create_puzzle()
    words = funcs.get_words()
    funcs.print_puzzle(rawPuzzle)
    puzzle = funcs.format_puzzle(rawPuzzle)
    vertPuzzleRaw = funcs.make_vert_puzzle(puzzle)
    vertPuzzle = funcs.format_vert_puzzle(vertPuzzleRaw)
    for x in range(len(words)):
        word = words[x]
        for l in range(len(puzzle)):
            forward = funcs.check_forward(puzzle, word, l)
            if forward != -1:
                print(word, ':  (FORWARD)', 'row: ', l, 'column: ', forward)
            backward = funcs.check_backward(puzzle, word, l)
            if backward != -1:
                print(word, ':  (BACKWARD)', 'row: ', l, 'column: ', (9 - backward))
            down = funcs.check_down(vertPuzzle, word, l)
            if down != -1:
                print(word, ':  (DOWN)', 'row: ', down, 'column: ', l)
            up = funcs.check_up(vertPuzzle, word, l)
            if up != -1:
                print(word, ':  (UP)', 'row: ', (9 - up), 'column: ', l)
        if forward and backward and down and up == -1:
                print(word, ': word not found')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and the output looks like this:

```
Puzzle: 

WAQHGTTWEE
CBMIVQQELS
AZXWKWIIIL
LDWLFXPIPV
PONDTMVAMN
OEDSOYQGOB
LGQCKGMMCT
YCSLOACUZM
XVDMGSXCYZ
UUIUNIXFNU


UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX : word not found
UNIX :  (FORWARD) row:  9 column:  3
UNIX : word not found
CALPOLY :  (DOWN) row:  1 column:  0
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
CALPOLY : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
GCC : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO :  (FORWARD) row:  7 column:  2
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
SLO : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE : word not found
COMPILE :  (UP) row:  6 column:  8
COMPILE : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM :  (BACKWARD) row:  1 column:  4
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
VIM : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
TEST : word not found
```

Process finished with exit code 0
I cant make it not print the "word not found" if it finds the word and I can't make it print it only once for when the words really is not found in the puzzle

Comment: Change `if forward and backward and down and up == -1:` to `if forward == backward == down == up == -1:`

Comment: @Aran-Fey when I do that the output changes to:


`UNIX :  (FORWARD) row:  9 column:  3
CALPOLY :  (DOWN) row:  1 column:  0
CALPOLY : word not found
GCC : word not found
SLO :  (FORWARD) row:  7 column:  2
SLO : word not found
COMPILE :  (UP) row:  6 column:  8
COMPILE : word not found
VIM :  (BACKWARD) row:  1 column:  4
VIM : word not found
TEST : word not found`

Comment: Ah, the problem is that the values of `forward`, `backward`, `up` and `down` are overwritten every iteration, so when you check if they're all equal to -1, you're only checking if something was found in the last iteration. You're gonna need an extra variable: After `word = words[x]`, set `word_found = False`, in every `if ,,, != -1:` statement set `word_found = True`, and finally change `if forward and backward and down and up == -1:` to `if not word_found:`.